# Request method 'GET' is not supported & Errror 401 - Maven REST Api - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I am working on learning Maven & REST Api's by working on a project app that will allow patients to track their medicines, this requires each user to have an account.

I am trying to implement account support & logins using Spring Security and jwt tokens, however I a having great difficulty getting anywhere.

I have followed a few tutorials, and cant seem to find any solutions.

Whenever I attempt to access and end point via url I get an Error 401 in browser & the message within Intellij: "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]"

Here is a link to the git repo: https://github.com/Burrouwill/PatientMedicineInfo-Web-App

When I toggle auth.anyRequest().authenticated(); --> auth.anyRequest.permitAll() I am still able to see the raw JSON data for the endpoints that access data loaded into my database so I am sure that is working okay still.

When I check postgres once Maven app is up and running, I can see the admin User is populated into db.

However when I try and access any end point I get Error 401 in browser & Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]"

I cant see any annotations in my Controller classes that seem out of place, but I am obviously missing something.

Thanks very much in advance for your help! I have been going round in circles for about a week now.

I have included some information below, please let me know if I should include more or less. This is my first post of this sort of length, apologies if it is a bit messy.

Cheers!

Here is the console/Spring trace:

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.4)

2023-07-23T07:39:55.727+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.Application             : Starting Application using Java 20.0.1 with PID 18596 (C:\Users\wgrbu\Desktop\COMPSCI\PatientMedcineInfo\main\PatientDrugInfo\target\classes started by wgrbu in C:\Users\wgrbu\Desktop\COMPSCI\PatientMedcineInfo\main\PatientDrugInfo)
2023-07-23T07:39:55.730+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.Application             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-23T07:39:55.786+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-07-23T07:39:55.787+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-07-23T07:39:56.532+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-23T07:39:56.614+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 74 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-23T07:39:57.345+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-23T07:39:57.357+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-23T07:39:57.357+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-07-23T07:39:57.435+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-23T07:39:57.437+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1649 ms
2023-07-23T07:39:57.610+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-23T07:39:57.665+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-07-23T07:39:57.992+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-23T07:39:58.198+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@22903251
2023-07-23T07:39:58.200+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-23T07:39:58.233+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-07-23T07:39:59.298+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-07-23T07:39:59.309+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-07-23T07:40:02.836+12:00  WARN 18596 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-07-23T07:40:03.104+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@78168aa6, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@26ffbd72, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@26eaec18, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@231bf85d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@ee1bfa2, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@392e4e23, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1f4ec2b8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@cbec593, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6debb0d8, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1ff84566, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@d09eb4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@e1aa764]
2023-07-23T07:40:03.322+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-07-23T07:40:03.359+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-23T07:40:03.371+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.Application             : Started Application in 8.049 seconds (process running for 8.522)
2023-07-23T07:40:08.297+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-07-23T07:40:08.298+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-07-23T07:40:08.300+12:00  INFO 18596 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-07-23T07:40:18.380+12:00  WARN 18596 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]
2023-07-23T07:40:18.613+12:00  WARN 18596 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]

Here is my SecurityConfig Class & pom.xml file for context:

public class SecurityConfiguration {

```
private final RSAKeyProperties keys;

public SecurityConfiguration(RSAKeyProperties keys){
    this.keys = keys;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
    daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return new ProviderManager(daoProvider);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();
                auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                auth.requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            });

    http.oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    http.sessionManagement(
            session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    );

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getPublicKey()).build();
}

@Bean
public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(){
    JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getPublicKey()).privateKey(keys.getPrivateKey()).build();
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter(){
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtConverter;
}
```

}

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.4
 

com.example
PatientDrugInfo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>

```
<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Postgres Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Enable DEBUG or TRACE logs for spring security and edit your question to include your full logs